# How to extract numbers not followed by keyword

Tags: python, regex

I want to get decimal numbers from a string but not followed by '/套'.

```
pattern = '(\d{1,}\.{0,1}\d{0,}万{0,1}-{0,1}\d{0,}\.{0,1}\d{0,}万{0,1})元{0,1}(?!/套)'
string1 = 'item 1:298元/套起'
string2 = 'item 1:298元/m2起'
string3 = 'item 1:298/m2起'

result1 = re.findall(pattern, string1) #expected [], but return ['1', '298']
result2 = re.findall(pattern, string2) #expected [298], but return ['1', '298', '2']
result3 = re.findall(pattern, string3) #expected [298], but return ['1', '298', '2']
```

How to get the correct answer?

Thanks

Comment: {0,1} can be abbreviated to ?
{0,} can be abbreviated to *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind:

- `{0,1}` = `?`
- `{0,}` = `*`
- `{1,}` = `+`

Use

```
(\d+\.?\d*万?-?\d*\.?\d*万?)元?/(?!套)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/lMwU9H/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    万                  '万'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;?                       ';' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -?                       '-' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    万                  '万'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;?                       ';' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  元                  '元'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;?                       ';' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    套                 '套'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is fairly simple using look ahead and look behind...

```
(?<=:)(\d+)(?!.*套)    : Using positive look behind to make sure the number is preceded by a colon, doesn't include the colon in the "full match"
:(\d+)(?!.*套)         : Not using positive look behind; colon is included in "full match" but not in groups


(?<=:)(\d+)(?!.*套)
(?<=                   : Start of positive look behind
    :                  : String to search for
     )                 : End of positive look behind
      (                : Start of capture group
       \d+             : Capture any number 1 or more times
          )            : End of capture group
           (?!         : Start of negative look ahead
              .*       : Greedy "capture anything" before string we're trying to avoid
                套     : String we're trying to avoid
                  )    : End of negative look ahead
```